# PickList with large set of elements slows down in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, primefaces

I'm dealing with an issue in the last version of Primefaces community (5.1). Using it with JSF 2.1.29 and +1000 elements brings a terrible performance issue when using Google Chrome 38 browser, either in view loading and element transfer. I'm afraid it's all about a problem in Chrome's Javascript engine. Here you've got a very basic use case:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PickListTestBean implements Serializable {

    private DualListModel<String> values;

    public PickListTestBean() {
        List<String> source = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> target = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            source.add("value" + i);
        }
        values = new DualListModel<String>(source, target);
    }

    public DualListModel<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(DualListModel<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

}
```

And the view:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head />
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:pickList value="#{pickListTestBean.values}" var="val" 
                effect="none" itemValue="#{val}" itemLabel="#{val}" 
                showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true">
                <p:column>
                    #{val}
                </p:column>
            </p:pickList>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

That's properly working in FF and IE latest versions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a Primefaces issue, which I opened a ticket for, but they said they were not going to fix it since there are too many elements for the component (which is true). However, there is a way to make it more efficient. The function for item generation loops appending the HTML content directly over the DOM:

```
generateItems: function(list, input) {   
    list.children('.ui-picklist-item').each(function() {
        var item = $(this),
        itemValue = PrimeFaces.escapeHTML(item.attr('data-item-value')),
        itemLabel = item.attr('data-item-label'),
        escapedItemLabel = (itemLabel) ? PrimeFaces.escapeHTML(itemLabel) : '';

        input.append('<option value="' + itemValue + '" selected="selected">' + escapedItemLabel + '</option>');
    });
}
```

Overriding the `generateItems` function for the `PickList` improves the perfomance noticeably:

```
<script>
    PrimeFaces.widget.PickList.prototype.generateItems = function(b, a) {
        var output = '';
        b.children(".ui-picklist-item").each(function () {
            var e = $(this),
            f = PrimeFaces.escapeHTML(e.attr("data-item-value")),
            d = e.attr("data-item-label"),
            c = (d) ? PrimeFaces.escapeHTML(d) : "";
            output += '<option value="' + f + '" selected="selected">' + c + "</option>";
        })
        a.append(output)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight alteration to the above answer. In case you're only interested in the target selection and would like to use a large input as source you might want to use the following:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.PickList.prototype.generateItems = function(b, a) {
    var output = '';
    if(b === this.targetList) {
        b.children(".ui-picklist-item").each(function () {
            var e = $(this),
            f = PrimeFaces.escapeHTML(e.attr("data-item-value")),
            d = e.attr("data-item-label"),
            c = (d) ? PrimeFaces.escapeHTML(d) : "";
            output += ('<option value="' + f + '" selected="selected">' + c + '</option>');
        });
    }
    a.append(output);
};
```

This will make sure processing is only performed on the (smaller) target list. As a result the DualListModel will return zero elements in the source while returning the selection as target.